# OpenSearch Dynamic Mapping Template

Tags: opensearch

Can somebody point me to examples or correct documentation for dynamic mapping in opensearch. I am trying to translate the mapping from elastic over to OS.

```
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "tags": {
        "mapping": {
          "ignore_above": 512,
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "match": "tag.*"
      }
    },
    {
      "metrics_long": {
        "mapping": {
          "index": false,
          "type": "float"
        },
        "match_mapping_type": "long"
      }
    },
    {
      "metrics_double": {
        "mapping": {
          "index": false,
          "type": "float"
        },
        "match_mapping_type": "double"
      }
    },
    {
      "text_fields": {
        "mapping": {
          "norms": false
        },
        "match": "*"
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "fields.connection_state": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "tags.source": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "tags.interface_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "tags.neighbor_address": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "fields.af_data/prefixes_accepted": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "tags.vrf_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "fields.af_data/prefixes_advertised": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get anything that starts with tag.* to be mapped as a keyword. Do I need to move all these under the properties now or what is the correct structure in OS?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this also, but as best as I can gather, OpenSearch does not support dynamic mappings like this.  I think you have to explicitly define the mappings for each exact field name, which is really unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and it worked fine for me, I used this on my index_templates for opensearch versions 1.3.1 and 2.8...

the first settings section which is "index" is just there to show you where you should put the "mappings" and is completely optional, also you can set priority to whatever number you like

if the syntax looks weird to you be sure to first check how to create index_templates in opensearch

hope it helps...

```
{
     "index_patterns": [
       "test-dynamictemplates-log-*"
     ],
     "priority": 1000,
     "template": {
         "settings": {
             "index": {
               "number_of_shards": "3",
               "number_of_replicas": "1",
               "plugins": {
                   "index_state_management": {
                      "rollover_alias": "test-dynamictemplates-log-alias"
                   }
               }
             }
         },
         "mappings": {
           "dynamic_templates":[
             {
                 "message_text":{
                   "match_mapping_type":"string",
                   "mapping":{
                       "type":"text",
                       "fields": {
                         "keyword": {
                           "type": "keyword",
                           "ignore_above": 256
                         }
                       }
                   }
                 }
             },
             {
                 "message_object":{
                   "match_mapping_type":"object",
                   "mapping":{
                       "type":"object"
                   }
                 }
             }
           ]
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**